# The intent doesn't work

Tags: android

**
good evening guys,

I have a problem with the intents in my app when i click on button "ADD" they don't work and show me "add activity " ,  ** 
that's the mainActivity

```
package com.hema.colornotes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button b1,b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btShow);

    }
    public void onAdd(){

        Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,add.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onShow(){
        Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,show.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

and that's the add class

```
package com.hema.colornotes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class add extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText note;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    }

    public void onSave() {
        note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNote);
        String notes = note.getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, show.class);
        i.putExtra("message", notes);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onCancel()
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

and that's the show class

```
package com.hema.colornotes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class show extends ActionBarActivity {
    Context context;
    List<String> tasks;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

        context = this;
        tasks = new ArrayList<String>();


        // second parameter is row layout,
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tasks);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String value = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

        tasks.add(value);

        // this method will refresh your listview manually
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

thank you in advance 
i hope that anyone reply to my question .

Answer (score 0):

Have to stated the new intent activity in your Manifest file.

You need to post log cat as well to make it easier to solve for us...

```
<activity
            android:name=".add"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>`

<activity
            android:name=".show"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

EDIT: I just realized what you wanted you have to call onClickListener on the buttons so:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onAdd();
            }
        });`

b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onShow();
            }
        });`
```

Comment: it worked but show activity doesn't work 
and add activity appears horizontally not vertically

Comment: You code and question is too vague. You need to specify what you want clearer.